# Pandas files not found

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, tensorflow

i can't understand why Pandas not found my fer2013.csv. I have this code:

```
class DataManager(object):
    """Class for loading fer2013 emotion classification dataset or
        imdb gender classification dataset."""
    def __init__(self, dataset_name='imdb', dataset_path=None, image_size=(48, 48)):

        self.dataset_name = dataset_name
        self.dataset_path = dataset_path
        self.image_size = image_size
        if self.dataset_path != None:
            self.dataset_path = dataset_path
        elif self.dataset_name == 'imdb':
            self.dataset_path = '../datasets/imdb_crop/imdb.mat'
        elif self.dataset_name == 'fer2013':
            self.dataset_path = '../datasets/fer2013/fer2013.csv'
        elif self.dataset_name == 'KDEF':
            self.dataset_path = '../datasets/KDEF/'
        else:
            raise Exception('Incorrect dataset name, please input imdb or fer2013')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_model.py", line 55, in <module>
    faces, emotions = data_loader.get_data()
  File "C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\erecog\utils\datasets.py", line 31, in get_data
    ground_truth_data = self._load_fer2013()
  File "C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\erecog\utils\datasets.py", line 57, in _load_fer2013
    data = pd.read_csv(self.dataset_path)
  File "C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\erecog\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f     
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\erecog\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 448, in _read        
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\erecog\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 880, in __init__     
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\erecog\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\devel\Documents\Proyectos\erecog\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__    
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 374, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File ../datasets/fer2013/fer2013.csv does not exist: '../datasets/fer2013/fer2013.csv'
```

I have that file in that folder, i don't know why it not found my file.

[image]

Comment: Your process may be running not in the same directory where the files are stored. Call `os.getcwd()` to find out.

Comment: Its working in the same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error. Thanks to @DYZ i could see the directory where the process was working, the process was out the 'utils' folder. I changed the route to './datasets/fer2013/fer2013.csv' with the point '.' before the '/'.